# How to create a configurable Tab bar like music app in iPhone

Tags: iphone, tabbar

I want to implement a configurable tab bar in my app like iphone music app where a user can edit the Tab bar by dragging and dropping icon on to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UITabBarController handles this completely automatically. If you add more than 5 tabs to the tab controller then the fifth button changes to 'More' to allow the user to access the configuration interface.

If you want to customise the behaviour or do something completely different then implement the [UITabBarDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) protocol.

Answer (score 1):

Well, then it's a good thing that UITabBar has this functionality built in.  Take a look at the following method:

```
UITabBar *mybar = [[UITabBar alloc] init];
[mybar beginCustomizingItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:tabItem1, tabItem2, nil]];
```